# Looking for source code repositories for AI Planning systems written in CLIPS

Tags: clips, clipspy

I have gone through github extensively.  Last time I checked the CLIPS tag was removed btw.

I am looking for CLIPS code repositories that contain AI Planners. Since the word CLIPS confuses many search engines, I was hoping the wider community might have better answers.  A single example planner that is more than 40 lines long, slightly more than a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github is the largest repository of CLIPS projects that I've found. I've seen a few planning projects there, mostly programs that move a robot to accomplish some goals.

Comment: Can you actually reference any one of the few you've seen?

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=CLIPS&q=CLIPS+robot&type=Repositories

Comment: I liked this one: https://github.com/srajat/Chess-using-CLIPS

Answer (score 0):

I found a generalized planning system written in CLIPS that was part of a Masters Thesis here: https://github.com/arcra/PlanningEngine